# How to use an if statement in conditional formatting for Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Right now I have a piece of code (in Google Sheets, Conditional Formatting) which takes a number from cell F3, then checks if it has a 0 at the end of it/in it, then it changes the colour of cells E4:I6. Now what I want to do, is that I want to change it so that it look at cell F3 and cell E3. Then checks F3 for a 0 and checks E3 for a 1. If they both have those specific numbers then it changes the colours of cells E4:N6.How do I do that? (Below is the code  I have right now.)

```
=REGEXMATCH(TEXT(INDIRECT("'Data'!F3"),"#"),"[0]$")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AND` function.

Just change the formula you are applying to:

```
=and(
  REGEXMATCH(TEXT(INDIRECT("'Data'!F3"),"#"),"[0]$"),
  REGEXMATCH(TEXT(INDIRECT("'Data'!E3"),"#"),"[1]$")
)
```

Don't forget to change the range of the conditional cells to be from `E4:I6` to `E4:N6`.

For more information about the [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292) language used, you can check it [here](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)